# Can't understand this code — is it C?

Tags: system

Can anyone help me understand this snippet?  Is it even C?

```
lcd_bl: backlight {
    compatible = "pwm";
    level = <8>;
};
```

Specifically:

1. What is `lcd_bl`?

   I am assuming that `lcd_bl` is a label, but there is no `goto lcd_bl`. `lcd_bl` is referenced in this snippet which is in the same file as the one above

   ```
   lcd0: display {
       back = <&lcd_bl>;
   };
   ```
2. What data structure is `backlight`?
3. Why are `<>` used when assigning a number to a variable?
4. What is happening in the second snippet?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not C.. Where did you get it from? Looks like some hardware config file.

Comment: looks like a TI config file https://e2e.ti.com/support/arm/sitara_arm/f/791/p/557651/2040216

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Right. Looks like the "Device Tree Source" (dts) syntax used to describe the hardware in linux kernel.

Comment: I'm working on a project where we use a microprocessor from TI. Having some trouble getting the display to work.

Comment: You should add tags like `system` or `system-config` for this question. If you have trouble display it, looking for something existing project can parse this config file.

Comment: seem like a variant of https://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/791/rh812.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this code is C programming language. It's used for the development of the board AM437x. [more info](http://www.ti.com/tool/tmdxidk437x) about the board

take a look at **am4372.dtsi**,**dt-bindings/pinctrl/am43x** and **pwm** C libraries to understand this code if you are a senior C developer otherwise forget about it it's not novice level.